# How to properly Export results of select statement into Csv file using spool in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Code:

```
set heading off
  set arraysize 1
  set newpage 0
  set pages 0
  set feedback off
  set echo off
  set verify off

spool 'c:\farmerList.csv'
/

select FIRSTNAME','LASTNAME','TRN','CELL','PARISH

spool off
```

The file is being saved to the directory, however it is saving the "select FIRSTNAME','LASTNAME','TRN','CELL','PARISH" and not the results of the query in csv format. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: i have the same problem is it any solution please give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select is incomplete as you don't have a `from` clause, but not sure if you've lost that in the copy-and-paste. As it is there is nothing to run, since the partial statement is never executed (no terminating `;` or `/` on the next line). If you did have a `from farmers;` clause then it would show the command plus an ORA-00923 error, probably.

You can't just put a quoted comma between the fields, you need to concatenate the fields with that character using the `||` concatenation symbol:

```
spool 'c:\farmerList.csv'

select FIRSTNAME
    ||','|| LASTNAME
    ||','|| TRN
    ||','|| CELL
    ||','|| PARISH
from farmers;
```

gives a file containing

```
Joe,Grundy,X,Y,Ambridge
```

The fields don't have to be on separate lines, I jut find that easier to read and keep track of the commas.

You don't need the `/` after the spool command - that will re-excute the last statement before the `spool`, if there is one - and you don't need the quotes around the spool file name unless it contains spaces, but they don't hurt.

There's also a [`set colsep`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2698758) command which you can use to make the column separator into a comma, but you have to worry about padding, so I find it easier to concatenate the columns together as you're (almost) doing.

---

Except that's for SQL*Plus, as I didn't notice the SQL Developer reference in the title. Spool is a bit odd in Developer as it seems to trap and echo things you probably don't want, and not all of the `set` commands work (which ones depends on the version).

The safer and preferred way, I think, is to run a normal query without concatenated commas:

```
select FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, TRN, CELL, PARISH
from farmers;
```

and with 'run' rather than 'run script', so that the results appear in the grid view in the query result window. Right-click on the grid and choose 'export'. You can then save as a CSV, or even as an XLS, and can choose to not have a header row if you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

this is the correct solution please go through this

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class TableExport {
public static void main(String[] args) {

try{
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","name","password");
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet resultData = statement.executeQuery("select * from your_table");

            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File("D:/Uploads/Output5.csv")), '|');
            writer.writeAll(resultData, true);
            writer.close();

}catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error" +e);
    }
  }
}
```

if anyone likes this please note you would need oracle-jdbc.jar and opencsv1.7.jar in library folder to properly execute this code.